# Swift- how can a tableViewCell tab bar be setup?

Tags: swift, tabbar

I have this class below

```
  class CategoryCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
                      UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
     ..... ...
 }
```

I also have a tabbar controller. I was able to setup a tab for collection view class

```
let searchNavController = templateNavController(
         unselectedImage:    #imageLiteral(resourceName: "search_unselected"), 
         selectedImage:      #imageLiteral(resourceName: "search_selected"), 
         rootViewController: BusinessSearchController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()))
```

But for some reason, I can't figure out what is wrong or how to setup up a tab for the category cell. The code below shows this error

```
" Argument labels '(style:)' do not match any available overloads"
```

How can I setup the tabcontroller for category cell?

```
let homeNavController = templateNavController(
    unselectedImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "home_unselected"),
    selectedImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "home_selected"), 
    rootViewController: CategoryCell(style: .plain)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't setup tab for a `UICollectionViewCell` type. `BusinessSearchController` is a type of `UIViewController` and that's why you were able to add it to a `UITabBarController`. Basically, for tab bar you need `ViewControllers` not cells.

```
   class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
        override viewDidLoad() {
            // Tab bar class have a viewControllers Property
            viewControllers = [BusinessSearchController, ... your other controllers]
        }
   }
```